# Walking on a torus minimum distance

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, optimization

I was imagining a problem, about a torus (in general a well behaved 3D object). Let us pick two arbitrary non-identical points $A$ and $B$ on the surface of the torus. How would I calculate the shortest path connecting both points?

I don't know how to start this problem. I think I need to calculate the length of a path in 3D parametrized by $\boldsymbol{c}(t)$ ($\boldsymbol{c}(t=0)=A$,$\boldsymbol{c}(t=1)=B$) and then add the surface of the torus via Lagrange Multipliers.

$$L=\int_{t=0}^{t=1}||\boldsymbol{c}(t)||dt+\lambda F,$$

in which $F$ would be the equation describing the surface of the Torus.

Would that be an appropriate approach? I think that it would be necessary to pick a different coordinate system (e.g. torus coordinates). I know that the solution is not always unique.

Comment: What you are looking for is the Euler-Lagrange equation, I think. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation

Comment: I didn't know how to implement the constraint into the Euler-Lagrange equations.I would be glad If you could outline this approach using the Euler-Lagrange equations.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer merely provides some resources.*

What you are looking for is a [geodesic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Geodesic.html) on a torus.

Check out these two resources (especially the first if you have training in physics):

- [Geodesics on the Torus and other Surfaces of Revolution Clarified Using Undergraduate Physics Tricks with Bonus: Nonrelativistic and Relativistic Kepler Problems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6206)
- [The Curvature and Geodesics of the Torus](http://www.rdrop.com/~half/math/torus/torus.geodesics.pdf)