# Isometry of the torus and sphere to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, geodesic

My use of the technical language might be incorrect, so I'll try to explain it in simpler terms.

Let $G$ be a torus (or a sphere) in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I am looking for a function $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $d_G(x,y)=d_{\mathbb{R}}(f(x),f(y))$ where $d_{G}(x,y)$ is the length of the shortest path defined over the surface of the torus (or sphere) between points $x$ and $y$, and $d_{\mathbb{R}}(x,y)=|x-y|$.

I would image $f$ will be different for sphere and torus. There are related questions and resources such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180608/walking-on-a-torus-minimum-distance), and [this](http://www.rdrop.com/%7Ehalf/math/torus/geodesics.xhtml) that shows different geodesics over the torus, but none of them have an explicit form for $f$. Is there such explicit form?

I think the sphere is a little easier, since the geodesics are always given by arc lengths that depend on the angle between the two points. So, the problem becomes a matter of finding the angle between any two points in the sphere. However, [here](http://physicspages.com/pdf/Relativity/Geodesic%20equation%20-%20geodesics%20on%20a%20sphere.pdf) they consider differential equations, which to my naïve understanding seems overly complicated (it may be they are just being rigorous).

Overall, I'd appreciate if someone can share a resource or a closed form of $f$, or let me know in case getting such $f$ is not trivial.

I know there are many resources out there on differential geometry, but many use jargon and go deeper than what I want at the moment. With this question I am looking for answers/resources that keep things understandable even for those that don't know any differential geometry.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, what you are asking for is impossible, as it would imply that the torus could be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No such function exists. If $f$ exists as you have described then $f$ would be continuous and injective. To get a contradiction you can then apply the following general theorem: if $M$ is a 2-dimensional manifold then no continuous injective function $f : M \to \mathbb R$ exists. To prove this theorem, you would first apply the definition of a 2-manifold to obtain a continuous injection $g : D^2 \to M$, where $D^2 \subset \mathbb R^2$ is the closed unit disc, and then you would compose to get a continuous injection $f \circ g : D^2 \to \mathbb R$. Next, you can restrict to the unit circle $S^1 = \partial D^2$ to get a continuous injection $S^1 \mapsto \mathbb R$. But there does not exist any continuous injection $h : S^1 \to \mathbb R$: since $S^1$ is compact, $h$ has a maximum value $h(p)$ for some $p \in S^1$; you can then use the intermediate value theorem to find two points $s,t$ near $p$ such that $h(s)=h(t)$, contradicting injectivity.

Comment: So, the fact that such $f$ does not exists implies that if you want to color the torus or sphere (assuming $\min(f(x))$ is black and $\max(f(x))$ is white and the values in between get shades of gray), then there is no way to color it such that the coloring looks smooth (i.e., no abrupt changes between colors within a small neighborhood on the surface)?

Comment: That last question is not clear to me; I'm not sure what kind of coloring you intend. Perhaps if you could ask it clearly, it might make another good post.

Comment: I made another post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4299638/coloring-a-torus-or-a-sphere-continuously hopefully it is clear this time.