# coloring a torus or a sphere continuously

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, geodesic

This question is based on another question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4299502/isometry-of-the-torus-and-sphere-to-mathbbr/4299511?noredirect=1#comment8954198_4299511).

Let $G$ be a torus or a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I will work with a sphere because I think it is easier. The goal is to color the surface of the sphere using [white, black, and grey scales](https://www.artwork.com/gdsii/pixelmap/greybar.gif). The goal is to color points that are the farthest apart (the notion of distance is the shortest distance over the surface) with black and white (it does not matter which one white and which one black) and points that are close with similar colors.

Then, the north pole would be black and the south pole would be white (since they are the farthest apart possible). However, one can take any other two opposite points, $a$ and $b$, and would have to color them black and white, respectively, but then $a$ is black and the south pole is white, but they are not the farthest apart. Hence this shows that such coloring is not possible.

My question is: is this equivalent to the statement (with the proof) of the my previous question, namely: that there is no $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $d_G(x,y)=d_{\mathbb{R}}(f(x),f(y))$ where $d_{G}(x,y)$ is the length of the shortest path defined over the surface of the torus (or sphere) between points $x$ and $y$, and $d_{\mathbb{R}}(x,y)=|x-y|$.

Or could this reasoning be used a proof of my previous question?

Comment: This continues to make no sense. The north pole is close to the Arctic, and so all those should be approximately the same color. Who cares about the south pole? You need to be talking about a coloring on the set of (unordered) pairs of points in the sphere, not on points themselves.

Comment: Why pairs? $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the coloring function basically and you want to assign color $f(x)$ to point $x$, where $f_{\max}=\sup_{x\in G}f(x)$ gets white and the infimum gets black (or vice versa).

Comment: I already explained this. There exists no coloring function as you describe it. By symmetry, the sphere must all be gray, since every point is close to a disk around it. (I see that you had already deduced a contradiction from assuming the existence, which I missed the first time through.)  By connectedness, the gray color propagates everywhere. The only way to make sense of this is to color the space of pairs of points (which, mathematically, is the quotient of $S^2\times S^2$ by $\Bbb Z_2$).

Comment: I don't entirely understand your argument, but I think it has the right flavor. The [borsuk-ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) says that any continuous function from the sphere to $\mathbb{R}^2$ must take the same value on opposite points. In particular if $f : S^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is your (continuous) coloring function, then necessarily there will be two points maximally far from each other which get the same color. In particular, they won't be a white/black pair.

Comment: Ted, yes, that's all I needed to know. @Halla yes, my thinking was going along those lines.